# elastic4s - control the analyzer to use in term query

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic4s

I want to control the analyzer in my search query.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
client.execute(search in indexName / documentType query {
  bool {
    must(
      termQuery("email", email),
      termQuery("name", name)
    )
  }
}
```

How can I control the analyzer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a `term` query does not analyze the search terms, so what you're looking for is probably a `match` query instead and it would go like this:

```
client.execute(search in indexName / documentType query {
  bool {
    must(
      termQuery("email", email),
      matchQuery("name", name)              <--- change this to match query
         .analyzer(StandardAnalyzer)        <--- add this line
    )
  }
}
```

The test cases are a good source of information as well. In the [`SearchDslTest.scala`](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/02494f01d1d9782f0b34be2c5fd4650061f1d53f/elastic4s-core-tests/src/test/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s/SearchDslTest.scala#L138) file you'll find how to set all possible properties of a `match` query.

Comment: Thanks! is there a way to use a costume analyzer I created as part of my mapping? somehow tell the query, look here, and use this analyzer?

Comment: Yes, you can [define your own analyzer](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/ca409b775fd0acbd65c143c60cb1ef4ed5ee079b/elastic4s-core/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s/analyzers/AnalyzerDsl.scala)  and then use it like any pre-defined ones.

Comment: Looks like there is an option to define a custom anlayzer, but don't have the option to specify an already defined analyzer which was already defined as part of my index settings. is that right?

Comment: I think you can pass in there anything that has a `name` property, so you can create a "fake" analyzer having the same name as the one you have already defined in your index and it should work. Best is to try it out.